# confusing term - "pulling a request"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, definition

To **pull** by the most common definition means (by Merriam-Webster)

> to exert force upon so as to cause motion toward the force

so it is understandable (to me) that to pull a show/license indicates to cancel a show/license (as in to pull a show out of a pre-determined schedule or to pull a license out of its utility)

But to **pull a robbery** means to **commit/carry out a robbery**, which seems VERY different from the most common meaning of the verb.

So does **pulling a request** (a general use, not an IT-elated computer jargon) means.

> 1. the request will be cancelled (i.e. pulled away from a system)

or

> 2. the request will be carried out

To put the term in context, I realized the term in my case actually probably means to "carrying out the request", not "cancelling the request". Can a native speaker confirm it ?

> "Typically cell requests are pulled once every day in the morning. So if you put in a request in the afternoon, it will be pulled the next morning".

Based on this, it means

a request can be **pulled** to a "execution list" or a "disregard list", which depends on the context and can be truly confusing. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

In administrative law-type and some slang lingo, **pull** means to remove.

- They pulled my application for employment. [removed it from some place]
- We were pulled from that team and put on another team.
- "Have you pulled the invalid ballots from the ballot box?"

So, "pull a request" means to remove it from some place or separate it from other requests.

The aspect these share (semantic trait) in terms of meaning is that **pull** here means to remove or separate some object or person from one group and put them in another.

Comment: It's not exactly in common use, but my "default" understanding of ***to pull a [request, application, invitation,...]*** would be to ***cancel / withdraw*** it. On the other hand, context might make it clear the intended meaning was ***to fetch / produce it*** (the document itself, from a filing cabinet or whatever). And I expect there's a more *specific* sense relating to document version control systems, but I'm not well up on how push and pull "requests" work in, say, GitHub.

Comment: to cancel or withdraw it means you remove it from the list of invitees and put it in the uninvited list.  Also, with getting it from a filing cabinet: if you pull it, that means you remove it from that place and put it on your boss's desk, for example. **Remove from one place and put in another is the common semantic trait for this meaning.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91657/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-confusing-term-pulling-a-request).

Answer (score -1):

**"To pull a (noun)" is a common idiomatic slang phrase meaning "to do something in the manner of (said noun)"**, eg. "Pull a Nixon", meaning to resign *(I made that one up, as its usage is largely context-related. Here, it refers to former US President Richard Nixon's resignation).* This usage is probably the closest to "pull a robbery", though **I've never heard "pull a robbery" used.**

I've also never heard "pull a request", although that one might be more common in certain circumstances in life than others. I suspect "pull a request" could be either depending on context, although "pull a request" sounds weird to me if used as "execute a request".

Comment: "pull a robbery or heist" is very common in fact. The other meaning to do something in the manner of is not relevant here. Don't you watch detective etc. movies?

Comment: @Lambie In those contexts, I've heard "pull ***off*** a robbery/heist. Is that what you meant?